# How to parse this json in angular js using ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to parse this json in angular js using ngrepeat but it is not giving length. Can anybody please tell me how to parse this json

```
{
  "item1": {
    "timing": "9:15-12:30,15:00-21:15,13:00-14:30",
    "price": 45,
    "session": "breakfast",
    "check": false
  },
  "item2": {
    "timing": "10:15-12:30,15:00-18:15",
    "price": 55,
    "session": "breakfast",
    "check": true
  },
  "item3": {
    "timing": "15:00-18:15",
    "price": 25,
    "session": "snacks",
    "check": true

  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div ng-repeat="tempdata in jsonData">
<div>{{tempdata.timing}}
</div>
<div>{{tempdata.price}}
</div>
....
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve through ng-repeat but i got stuck
Regards

Comment: You are trying how? Please show your code. You have an object and objects have no length (arrays do) and the `ng-repeat` docs show you how to repeat an object

Comment: @charlietfl Can u please post a link which explains it?

Comment: Can you please show your approach with code?

Comment: @NutBoltu I updated my code. Please check

Comment: @Kumar You are running ng-repeat over a key-value object. Your json data is not an array. So you need to use key value to retrieve the data. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Kumar please let me know if it works or not

Comment: The link is easily found by going to angular documentation site and looking at `ngRepeat` and reading all the various approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to do something like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,val) in jsonData">
  <p>{{jsonData[key]["timing"]}}</p>
  <p>{{{jsonData[key]["price"]}}</p>
</div>
```

If you are making an http request to receive your json data, remember that the angular http service returns a promise and you will need to handle that before adding the data to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are running ng-repeat over a key-value object. Your json data is not an array. So you need to use key value to retrieve the data.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in jsonData">
     <div>{{jsonData[key].timing}}
     </div>
    <div>{{jsonData[key].price}}
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

and also jsonData has no length as it is an object.

Comment: @NutBoltuThanks for response

Comment: If my answer helps you please upvote it or make it right answer